# Differences of h.264 and h.265?

Tags: h.264, h.265

What are the main differences between h.264 and h.265?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding),  the new video coding standard brings promise of huge bandwidth savings of approx. 40-45% over H.264 encoded content

[image: H.265 VS H.264]

[More info here](http://www.mediaentertainmentinfo.com/2013/10/4-concept-series-what-is-the-difference-between-hevc-h-265-and-h-264-mpeg-4-avc.html)

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot for this comprehensive comparison! Lots of things make sense to me now; however something that is odd though is that h.264 is actually capable of 4K! Every time I see people talking about 4K it's on the h.265 context even if it requires more computing power; I guess the bandwidth saving makes up for that!

Comment: @Raj Is this table something you made yourself, or does it come from somewhere else? If it's the latter maybe you could provide a link.

Comment: Sure i will provide a link.

Comment: Cheers, useful info. One thing though, can you add some detail on which supports 8-bit vs 10-bit vs 12-bit? As well as colour gamuts supported?

Answer (score 3):

h.265 is obviously more compressed than h.264 and was built for UHD and 4K. Though 1080 files still look great and are even smaller when encoded with h.265 than h.264. Some computers may have trouble with the new codec since it is so new. But, without being too technical, you can think of h.265 and being the new h.264.

Comment: Do you expect 265 replacing 264 in the future, as far as web video goes?

Comment: I think that's absolutely where the tech is heading, it's just in its infancy now so it will just take a bit longer for everything to catch up.

Comment: Basically h.265 uses the same techniques to compress video, it just does it *better*. The tradeoff for this is that it needs more computing power, especially to compress. So some older machines may struggle with it.